# How to get cell id from cell value in excel file with python?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

For example I have a cell that this text is in it: "hi!"

So I have the cell's value, But I don't know how to get the id of it ( for example "C2" ).

How should I do it?

I have also worked with "openpyxl". Reading rows and columns, writing texts to cells, getting cell values by cell ids and... But don't know this one...

Comment: The docs for [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, I have worked with "openpyxl". But don't know how to do this...

Comment: What you have you tried so far? please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70056533/edit) question and add that in.

Comment: ok. I will do it...